# MacPorts is not installing

Tags: macports, theos

I am getting error while installing macports using this command

```
sudo port install dpkg
```

Error: -bash: port: command not found

I am installing theos (ref http://brandontreb.com/beginning-jailbroken-ios-development-getting-the-tools/) , OS is **MoutainLion** and **xCode** is 4.5

Comment: How did you install macports?

Comment: I have download the package from MacPorts website.
[link](http://www.macports.org/)

Comment: Then it should have added something like `export PATH=/opt/local/bin"$PATH` to your ~/.profile or similar file so port etc is put on your path which is not true in your case.So which shell are you using?